# Can "either" be used with "nor"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

Can I say, for example, "You aren't either pretty nor funny"? And if so, is it any different from saying "You aren't either pretty or funny"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say anything you like. Whether your listeners have the same understanding of what you are saying as you have, or immediately apprehend it, is something else altogether.

The normal collocation is *neither . . . nor* for these sorts of things. *Not either* has a very strange sound.

There are times when one uses *nor* following a negative that is something other than *neither*.

- I’m not going and neither are you.
- I will have nothing to do with it, nor will you, either.
- I had no problems left, nor any complaint.

But this is not one of those.  Mostly the problem is that *not either* really  doesn’t occur directly juxtaposed like that; one must say *neither* when one means *not either*.

I only mean they don’t fall immediately together.  I don’t rule out negative polarity items like, where *neither* would in turn be ungrammatical:

- I’m not having any of those either.

So it is *neither the one nor the other* in the negative and *either the one or the other* in the positive.  Don’t try to mix those. It doesn’t make sense.

I don’t know whether you are a native speaker of Spanish, but if you are, it is just like the *ni . . . ni* collocation versus the *o . . . o* collocation: you cannot mix those.  *Ni el uno ni el otro* is fine, as is *o el uno o el otro* as well, but you cannot have one of one and the other of the other.  Don’t mix them:  *o el uno ni el otro* is just going to confuse people and sound wrong.

By the same token, don’t pair *nor* with *either*: it just sounds confusing.

Answer (score 1):

*Neither* should be used with *nor,* and *either* with *or.*

"You aren't either pretty nor funny" is simply incorrect.

"You aren't either pretty or funny" is arguably acceptable but "You are neither pretty nor funny" is much more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Writing *You're not pretty nor funny* would also be acceptable.

Saying neither/nor is the logically equivalent of saying "You are not pretty and not funny". Saying "You are not pretty or funny" can be parsed to mean "Either you are not pretty or else you are funny."

Answer (score 0):

'either" has a lot of uses you should study in a grammar or in a dictionary such as OALD.
"either" has two basic meanings:

In "on either side of the road were trees" the meaning is: on each of the two sides there were trees.

The second meaning is "one of two". 
In "You can have either A or B" it means "you can have only one thing, A or B, but not both. You can read such a sentence as "You can have either of the two things: A or B. (A and B stand for a thing, whatever you like.)

A structure such as "either A nor B" makes no sense as the meaning would be: 
One of two things, A and not B. And such a structure is nonsense.

There are more uses of "either", but I don't want to repeat OALD or similar dictionaries.